# Integral limits placement with unicode-math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, integral

I'm struggling with integral limits placement when the `unicode-math` package is used (both under *LuaLaTeX* and *XeTeX*). The following example illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\displaystyle
\int\nolimits_0^1f(x)dx=\lim\nolimits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^nf\left(\frac in\right)
\)

\bigskip
\(\displaystyle
\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf\left(\frac in\right)
\)

\bigskip
\(
\int\nolimits_0^1f(x)dx=\lim\nolimits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^nf\left(\frac in\right)
\)

\bigskip
\(
\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf\left(\frac in\right)
\)
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the lower limit is positioned differently with `unicode-math` (and *LuaLaTeX* 1.0.0 from MikTeX distribution)

[image: with unicode-math]
and without `unicode-math`

[image: without unicode-math]

Is this a `unicode-math` issue, or the Latin Modern Math font issue? Though, other math fonts show similar behavior and shift the lower integral limit down and a bit left (STIX Two Math for example). Or may be it's the LuaTeX engine issue (XeTeX though also moves the lower limit in the same direction as LuaTeX)?

Note, that `\int\limits` places the limits a bit differently from the original LaTeX engine as well. It shifts the upper limit to the right a bit, and the lower limit to the left a bit.

So where to report this? I think that the original limit placement looks better.

Comment: The placing is different between luatex and pdftex. But it is again different with a luatex 1.0.4. (which you could get by using miktex next). I don't see the "touching" there.

Comment: it is using a different font and a different math layout implementation so you can't expect them to be exactly the same

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I understand that. Though I'd assume that this big difference isn't desirable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Good to hear that. I'll try to get the update and look at the changes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Unfortunately, with LuaTeX 1.0.4 the result looks exactly the same.

Comment: It seems that the kerning information in Latin Modern Math is suboptimal.